# C++ search through 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

I've got a 2d array airport[30][5] which prints out like this:

Departure, Destination, Airline, Price, Duration

I want the user to enter in their own departure and destination (stored in variables x and y), and then I will search through the array to see if the first two elements of each row matches what the user has input. If they both match, I want to print out all the rows where they both match.

So far I have a simple loop but it prints out all the lines in the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < 30; j++) {
        if(airport[i][0] == x && airport[i][1] == y) {
            cout << Line(s) from array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You realize (a) `i` is only indexing the first **5** of your **30** dominant slots, and (b) `j`is unused in the loop body it is iterating. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
for(int j=0; j < 30; j++) {
    if(airport[j][0] == x && airport[j][1] == y) {
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
            cout << airport[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only one loop

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if ( airport[i][0] == x && airport[i][1] == y) {
            // cout << Current Line from array
        }
}
```